# Joomla article layout

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am a beginner of Joomla. Now I simply want to align the image in a article to right of the text.

I did select "right" in the align drop down option when I insert the image, it looks fine in the editor - the image is in the right, but it still goes to left in the real site. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your template css is overriding article images. Can you provide a link to your site so it can be inspected?

Answer (score 0):

Check you article in HTML edit mode in the editor and make sure your image and text sit inside the same

tag.  They usually don't and thats why its not looking right. This works most of the time for me.